# jquery fadeOut() works but slideUp() doesn't

Tags: jquery

Very simple script here but I can't work out why it's not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="services-tab">...</div>

<div id="services-content">...</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".services-tab").click(function(){
    $("#services-content").slideUp();
  });
});
```

If I replace slideUp() with fadeOut() it works, but this isn't the effect that I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you re-create it at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VjKn5/1/

Comment: I've created a fiddle and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ftTLz/.

Comment: Do you have some css that interfers with this? jQuery slideUp function works by setting the height of the element and `display:none` when the animation is done.

Comment: Hi Guys, see my solution. I still don't know the problem with the Foundation4 library, but loading jquery directly worked.

Comment: It's because the code doesn't actually load jQuery but [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) which has similar syntax.

Answer (score 0):

remove # from id

```
<div id="#services-content">...</div>
```

replace it by

```
<div id="services-content">...</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It's already as id="services-content".

Comment: Yep it doesn't make sense, if the typo was in the source, fadeOut wouldn't work  either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is solved. I've been using Foundation4, which loads the jquery with this:

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src=' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
  </script>
```

So instead, I loaded jquery directly:

And now it works.

Comment: May I recommend you close this question?  It's a bit localised to be of much use to anyone, unless you edit it perhaps to ask why Foundation4 seems to conflict with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add below references in your code and it will solve your problem

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

And [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chn6d/) For live demo with using for this Jquery..

Answer (score 0):

Use this latest jquery library.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

its work.